# WooCommerce Shipping Calculator required fields "shipping calculator.php"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to convert country, zipcode and city fields as required fields including text in below code.

Code: [templates/cart/shipping-calculator.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/templates/cart/shipping-calculator.php)

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. Pure code-writing requests and/or recommendations to find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to show [what you have tried so far to solve your problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

To make fields required on the cart page calculator I think the best option is to copy the template file into your theme. Then add reqired tag to your inputs.

```
<input required type="text" class="input-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode() ); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Postcode / ZIP', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" name="calc_shipping_postcode" id="calc_shipping_postcode" />
```

Comment: Dear Martin above note highly appreciated. What about dropdown selections?

Comment: By default woo gets your store Country / State setting so its always filled. Select will grab first available option if we remove the default one. Select also accepts required so edit dropdown to your needs.